# How to get calendar events from o365 connection in Microsoft PowerApps?

Tags: outlook, office365, powerapps

I'm currently testing some stuff with Microsoft PowerApps. My aim is to create an app, which shows the calendar events of my office 365 account. I've applied the connection to office 365, and was able to get emails. But I don't know how to get the events, because nothing is documented. In the PowerAppStudio environment I can see that functions such as `Office365.CalendarGetItem(...` are available but the syntax is unclear. Please, can someone explain to me how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

My experience as follows;

You need to use

```
Office365Outlook.CalendarGetTables()
```

to get the Calendar object.Names and

```
Office365Outlook.CalendarGetItems()
```

To get the Calendar items for that object.

To demonstrate:

1. Add your Office365 outlook connector
2. Create a dropdown and take note of the name, or give it a new name
3. Set the Items value of the dropdown to **Office365.CalendarGetTables().value**

This gives you a your reference to get calendar items from - which you can now do with a gallery;

1. Add a gallery (I just pick a layout template I like and reconfigure)
2. Set the Items value of the gallery to **Office365.CalendarGetItems(YourDropDownName.Selected.Name).value**
   where YourDropDownName is the name of the dropdown you created.

It will, by default, list from today's meetings onwards.
There are some filter options with CalendarGetItems, the syntax is as follows;

```
Office365Outlook.CalendarGetItems (string table, [advanced][Optional]string $filter, [advanced][Optional]string $orderby, [advanced][Optional]integer $skip, [advanced][Optional]integer $top)
```

I use this great reference as well [PowerApps reference](https://www.carlosag.net/downloads/PowerApps-Connectors-Reference.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select a calendar where the items will be read.

```
Office365.CalendarGetItems(name of your calendar).value
```

Comment: Nope, your answer isn't working. Currently there is seemingly no way to make the calendar functions available. The following quote stands on a microsoft powerapps-website 

"As of this writing, the functions for calendar and contacts aren't supported."

Comment: Yes it is possible to read items from calendar. I did it in an microsoft power app ussing that code. If you look in microsoft flows you can see this function also. I would like to post a picture but i cannot... good luck

Answer (score 0):

Add the Office 365 connector as a connection
Create blank form 
Add a listbox
Set ListBox>Items = Office365.CalendarGetTables().value.DisplayName
Add a gallery
Change gallery style to be Title and subtitle on Data tab
Dry gallery>Items = Office365.CalendarGetTables().value

You can now see your calendars and their names.

I'm going to futz around further with this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "My experience" answer, I had to change "Office365." to "Office365Outlook.". I suspect content errors as the example of advanced options used "Office365Outlook.CalendarGetItems".

So

Office365.CalendarGetTables().value
Office365.CalendarGetItems(YourDropDownName.Selected.Name).value

became

Office365Outlook.CalendarGetTables().value
Office365Outlook.CalendarGetItems(YourDropDownName.Selected.Name).value

My Power Apps data source was "Office365Outlook" and my own email account at https://outlook.office.com/mail/inbox .

These worked for me.